# Visual Studio - static library won't link

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, static-libraries, static-linking

I created a static library (designated A) in Visual Studio that includes some header files from another library (designated B). Because that is a static library I didn't need to worry about the .lib file from A. When I created a console app (designated C) and added the .lib and header files from B as well as the header and .lib files from A. When I try to compile C it comes up with unresolved externals, not related to A, but to B.

I created two more test projects, a static library and a console app. The static library still used A and the console app still used A and the new static library, and it managed to compile fine, even without the header files of A.

I've run through all differences and I can't see any that would stop C from compiling. The only difference is the folder the projects are stored in. I have double-verified the locations of header files and .lib files and they are all there. How would I go about fixing the LNK2001 errors?

EDIT: I realised my post doesn't make much sense but when I try to use my library in another project it won't link at all and I can't see a reason why.

Comment: Is your method in the lib static?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To link with a .lib file, you just need to:

1,Add the path to the header file to the Additional Include Directories(property - >c/c++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories)

2,Add the path to the .lib file to the Additional Library Directories (property -> linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories)

3,Add the name of the .lib file with its extension to Additional Dependencies (property -> linker -> input -> Additional Dependencies)

If this issue couldn't be resolved, I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Linker Tools Error LNK2001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2001?view=vs-2019)

Comment: I've gone through that exact document and I've checked off everything. I can't get my library to work, even though freshly made ones will.

Comment: @liaquore, I suggest you should provide us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I just started adding bits of my code one by one and some parts of it work and some don't. Can the code actually affect whether a program can link or not?

Comment: @liaquore What is the error code? Can you provide the header file?

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT I had a similar problem. The thing is that I was assuming that project depending on base (.lib) was automatically importing (i.e. hence linking) to dependent project output without having to manually specify /LIBPATH and /L flags manually. For example, I use this feature a lot in VS for Fortran projects. Why it didn't work in this case? PS. I checked that option was on, but failed to work.